# Как правильно организовать верное наследование?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, generics

Существует класс `RecipeElement`. Существует так же в одном из классов с функционалом метод:

```
private void updateRecipeElements(RecipeElement element) {
        if (!mRecipeElements.contains(element)) {
            element.setParentRecipeUUID(mRecipe.getId().toString());
            mRecipeElements.add(element);
        }
}
```

Логика, как видите простая.

Через некоторое время мне потребовалось расширить функционал и так же добавить класс `RecipeStep`, у которого логика по обработке чем то схожа и одинаковое поле и метод (`setParentRecipeUUID`). По сему создал абстрактный класс, содержащий один параметр, геттер и сеттер:

```
public abstract class RecipeChild {
    public String mParentRecipeUUID;

    public String getParentRecipeUUID() {
        return mParentRecipeUUID;
    }

    public void setParentRecipeUUID(String parentRecipeUUID) {
        mParentRecipeUUID = parentRecipeUUID;
    }
}
```

Унаследовал класс `RecipeElement` и `RecipeStep` от него, для того что бы сделать вышеуказанный метод "универсальным" для объектов обоих классов, так как логика работы метода примитивна. 
Теперь метод выглядит так:

```
private void updateArrayOfChilds(RecipeChild element, ArrayList<RecipeChild> array) {
        if (!array.contains(element)) {
            element.setParentRecipeUUID(mRecipe.getId().toString());
            array.add(element);
        }
    }
```

Метод практически не притерпел изменений, за исключением одного входящего параметра - массива требуемых дочерних элементов, который и нужно использовать.

Но во время изменения возникла проблема - во время отработки метода в классе, где он объявлен - `updateArrayOfChilds(step, mRecipeSteps);` среда разработки предупреждает об ошибки компиляции в будущем [image: Ошибка]

Почему возникает исключение? Ведь мой класс RecipeStep (как и RecipeElement) унаследован он того класса, который "улучшенный" метод может принимать и тут должно происходить расширение типа (или нет?).
Как правльно в таком случае (если это вообще возможно) использовать дженерики?

**UPD**: Одну проблему решил изменив сигнатуру метода на `private void updateArrayOfChilds(RecipeChild element, ArrayList<? extends RecipeChild> array)` но в такм случае возникает проблема непосредственно внутри метода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте `<T extends RecipeChild> void updateArrayOfChilds(T element, ArrayList<T> array)`, если тип `element` известен на этапе компиляции и совпадает с типом содержимого `array`. Если нет, то я не думаю, что получится.

Comment: Да, тип известен, я так и сделал, помогло, спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую пояснить на примерах, почему появляются такие ошибки. У нас есть два типа с общим предком:

```
interface RecipeChild {}

class RecipeElement implements RecipeChild {}
class RecipeStep implements RecipeChild {}
```

и списки элементов этих типов:

```
ArrayList<RecipeElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<RecipeStep> steps = new ArrayList<>();
```

Нам нужен метод, который будет вставлять элемент указанного типа в список элементов этого типа (и что-то там еще делать).

Попробуем обойтись супертипом:

```
void addToList_supertype( RecipeChild element, ArrayList<RecipeChild> array ) {
    // работает
    array.add( element );
}

void addSome_supertype() {
    // The method addToList_supertype(RecipeChild, ArrayList<RecipeChild>)
    //   in the type Generics
    //   is not applicable for the arguments (RecipeElement, ArrayList<RecipeElement>)
    addToList_supertype( new RecipeElement(), elements ); 
}
```

Код не работает, т.к. генерики инвариантны (отношение наследования между типами в параметре не устанавливает отношение наследования между параметризованными типами) и `ArrayList<RecipeElement>` не является наследником `ArrayList<RecipeChild>`

Попытаемся сделать, чтобы `addToList` принимал списки наследников `RecipeChild`:

```
void addSome_wildcard_extends() {
    // работает, ура
    addToList_wildcard_extends( new RecipeElement(), elements ); 
}

void addToList_wildcard_extends( RecipeChild element, ArrayList<? extends RecipeChild> array ) {
    // но нет...
    // The method add(capture#1-of ? extends RecipeChild)
    //   in the type ArrayList<capture#1-of ? extends RecipeChild>
    //   is not applicable for the arguments (RecipeChild)
    array.add( element );
}
```

Тип `ArrayList<? extends RecipeChild>`- это не список, в котором находятся любые наследники `RecipeChild`, а список элементов какого-то типа, являющегося наследником `RecipeChild`. `ArrayList<RecipeElement>` подходит, поэтому вызов `addToList_wildcard_extends` работает, но `array.add( element )` мог бы добавить в `array` элемент произвольного типа (напр. `RecipeStep`) наследующего `RecipeChild`, поэтому компилятор такой вызов запрещает.

Читаем про PECS, видим там, что если данные передаются в аргумент (`array.add( element )`), то аргумент - потребитель (consumer), и нужно использовать `super`. Делаем:

```
void addToList_wildcard_super( RecipeChild element, ArrayList<? super RecipeChild> array ) {
    // работает
    array.add( element );
}

void addSome_wildcard_super() {
    // The method addToList_wildcard_super(RecipeChild, ArrayList<? super RecipeChild>)
    //   in the type Generics
    //   is not applicable for the arguments (RecipeElement, ArrayList<RecipeElement>)
    addToList_wildcard_super( new RecipeElement(), elements ); 
}
```

`array.add` заработал, поскольку `array` теперь список элементов с типом какого-то предка `RecipeChild`. Поскольку наследник может использоваться везде, где используется предок, добавление `child` в коллекцию ничего не сломает. Но сломался вызов `addToList`, поскольку `RecipeElement` - не предок `RecicpeChild`, и список `RecipeChild` не подходит.

Вспоминаем, что нам надо. Надо добавить объект какого-то *типа* в список объектов того же *типа*. Т.е. нам нужно объявить тип:

```
// объявляем тип-параметр T, расширяющий RecipeChild
<T extends RecipeChild> void addToList_type_parameter( T element, ArrayList<T> array ) {
    // работает, мы можем добавить элемент типа T в список элементов типа T
    array.add( element );
}

void addSome_type_parameter() {
    // работает, мы добавляем элемент типа RecipeElement в список RecipeElement
    addToList_type_parameter( new RecipeElement(), elements );

    // не работает, тип элементов списка не совпадает
    addToList_type_parameter( new RecipeElement(), steps ); 
}
```

Дальше можно снова вспомнить про PECS и использовать `ArrayList<? super T>`. Тогда метод сможет добавлять элементы не только в список того же типа, но и в списки предков:

```
<T extends RecipeChild> void addToList_type_parameter_super( T element, ArrayList<? super T> array ) {
    // работает, мы можем добавить элемент типа T в список элементов типа T
    array.add( element );
}

void addSome_type_parameter_super() {
    ArrayList<RecipeChild> children = new ArrayList<>();
    addToList_type_parameter_super( new RecipeElement(), children ); // работает
    addToList_type_parameter_super( new RecipeStep(), children );    // работает

    addToList_type_parameter_super( new RecipeElement(), steps ); // не работает
    // T == RecipeElement, RecipeStep не является супертипом RecipeElement 
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ! Я правильно понимаю, что использование в качестве типа массива конструкцию "? super T", а не "T extends RecipeChild" советует принципы PECS, пусть и похожи по результату?

Comment: @mamba0767 вы просто не сможете использовать методы обобщенного типа, тип аргумента которых объявлен с `extends`. Вообще, PECS - удобная (ну для англоговорящих) запоминалка на ковариантность (PE)/контравариантность (CS) ([вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29))

Answer (score 3):

Вам же среда разработки подсказывает, добавьте wildcard в сигнатуру:

```
private void updateArrayOfChilds(RecipeChild element, ArrayList<? extends RecipeChild> array)
```

Вот так всё будет в порядке

Comment: @iksay я буквально за несколько минут до вашего ответа сделал именно так, но далее возникает проблема внутри метода.

Comment: А что у вас за переменная `array`? Вы знакомы с принципом PECS (Producer extends consumer super)? рекомендую: https://habrahabr.ru/post/207360/

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку, требовалось добавить <T extends RecipeChild> в сигнатуре самого метода, а не параметров.